# Why + (or *) act different for than - (or /) with zero arguments?

Tags: clojure

When you call **+** with zero arguments

```
user=> (+)
0
```

I get **0** because it is invariant element to **+**. It works similar for *****

```
user=> (*)
1
```

Why this does not work for **-** and **/** ?

```
user=> (-)
ArityException Wrong number of args (0) passed to: core/-  clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:429)

user=> (/)
ArityException Wrong number of args (0) passed to: core//  clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:429)
```

Comment: I try to google it out with:lisp why + and - work differently

Comment: and: clojure why + and - work differently

Comment: There is no [identity element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element) for the [subtraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtraction#Properties) and [division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)) operations.

Comment: ...well, there is a **left identity element** inherited from resp. `+` and `*`. If it worked, it would be inconsistent too. A choice between inconsistency and inconsistency.

Comment: @D-side `0` and `1` are *right* identities for `-` and `/` respectively, not *left* identities. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element), for example.

Comment: @Thumbnail yep, my bad, `1 / n` is not exactly `n`. The point is the same though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the reason for this behaviour is the usage of `+` and `*` with aggregation functions: this allows to escape lots of boilerplate code in math formulas. Note the following:

```
(reduce + ()) => 0
(reduce * ()) => 1
```

the values are chosen not to affect the overall result of homogenous functions. Say you have to find the product of 10, 20, and all the items in some collection. That's what you do:

```
(defn product [items]
  (* 10 20 (reduce * items)))
```

so when you have some items in a coll, it will work perfectly predictable:

```
(product [1 2 3]) => (* 10 20 (* 1 2 3))
```

and when the coll is empty you get the following:

```
(product []) => (* 10 20 1)
```

so it is exactly what you would expect.

Similar works for `+`

So why doesn't it work for `-` and `/` ? 
i would say that they're not aggregation functions, traditionally they're opposite to aggregation. And in maths there are operators for `+` (   ∑ ) and `*` ( ∏ ), and no operators for `-` and `/`

Again, it's just a guess. Maybe there are some reasons that are much deeper.

Comment: 1+ You told the same thing as I wrote (or wanted to write), but more clearly.

Comment: yep you're right. I should probably read existing answers more attentively.

Answer (score 3):

Note that `-` and `/` work differently when they are given a single argument: `(- x 0)` is different from `(- x)`. The same for `(/ x 1)` and `(/ x)`. The practical argument for `+` and `*` is that when your arguments may not be known beforehand, you can just `apply` or `reduce` over a list (possibly empty). The same is not true for division and negation, because you seldom need:

```
(apply / list)
```

You at least have one argument:

```
#(apply / (cons % list))
```

This is not authoritative, just a guess.

Answer (score 2):

the technical explanation would be:

if you check `(source *)`,`(source +)` and `(source -)`

you will see that `*` and `+` can take 0 arguments while the `-` function will not.

```
(defn -
 ([x] (. clojure.lang.Numbers (minus x)))
 ([x y] (. clojure.lang.Numbers (minus x y)))
 ([x y & more]
   (reduce1 - (- x y) more)))
```